# Cannot award bounty

Tags: support, bounties

In [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/435003), I had [started a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/435003/timeline#history_6e0d1e8c-ec32-42bf-a831-fcbf7e0fff96) to draw more attention.

When I got an extensive [answer by user Eddie Kelley](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/435485), I awarded the bounty to that answer. Immediately after this, I found that there is another [answer by stackprotector](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/435443), who gave an even better explanation, and I accepted this answer.

I find it only fair to also give them an award for this answer, but I cannot see how to do it.

There is still a bounty button "+100" visible next to their answer, but when I click this, and I am asked whether I want to give away the 100 points, and I answered yes.

I got the response "This question has no open bounty". I guess I would need to create a new bounty instead, but I don't see how to do this. There is no "create bounty" link visible for this question. How can I award this user? Or, can I in general donate reputation points to a different user?

Comment: The link is "Start bounty" and it's below the comments under the question.

Comment: @Glorfindel : I could not find the _Start bounty_ link first, but now I see that it is clearly present. This is strange (I even used the _search_ function of Firefox to find all the occurances of the word _bounty_ on the page, without effect), but now looking at the place you indicated, it is clearly there, and it seems to work. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @user1934428 I added a sentence to the FAQ instead. I've seen half a dozen users with this problem in (what I feel is like) the past two years.

Comment: (And you're right, [apple.se] reputation and [so] reputation are different.)

Comment: @user1934428 I think that after you awarded the first bounty, the page didn't reload (I'm not sure if it's supposed to) and that's why you a) could still see the `+100` button next to the other answer(s) and b) couldn't find the "Start bounty" link (it wasn't there because of the "active" bounty). And it seems that once you refreshed the page, everything was back to normal.